# Use both WiFi and Lan to speed up the download

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, network-interface

In my office we have WiFi and RJ45 LAN connection to my laptop.  Both works well individually.  We do not use DHCP and hence I have configured two different static IPs for these interfaces.  While I observed through `tracert` command that WiFi is reaching the Internet through a different access provider than the LAN interface because WiFi uses a different gateway than the LAN.  This made me to wonder whether I could benefit of downloading part from WiFi and part by LAN there by reducing the total download time.

Is there any means by which I can use both interfaces to reduce the download time?

I saw many posts in SU about using simultaneously but not does not cover the doubling of speed.  My machine is x64 Windows 10 Pro and have admin rights.

Comment: You're talking about Link Aggregation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation. And the answer will be: No without a managed switch and specific laptop hardware. Maybe you can try http://speedify.com/desktop/

Comment: The best thing you can easily do is to make sure that your internet connection uses the faster of the two connections, by which I don't mean the higher raw speed (usually Ethernet), but the greater average down-load speed.